# I cant figure out the css styling this logo to save my life

Tags: html, css

I am working from a template and I understand most of the code, but I can't figure out what is causing this logo to double in size. There are two instances where the logo is rendered. One is at the top of the page and the other is in the toggled menu. Neither seems to have code causing this. I can't tell why it's doubling in size. It looks pixelated and bad.

```
<div class="menu-logo center-text">
   <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/logo.png"  alt="Tynd" />
   </a>               
</div>


<div class="header-logo center-text">
   <a href="index.html">
     <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Tynd">
   </a>               
</div>





.menu-logo img
{
transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}


.header-logo img
{
transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
```

The site is [Here](http://www.matthewtyndall.com) - It's the TYND logo

Comment: For CSS questions having the corresponding HTML available is generally considered a good idea. Many people are not likely to click on a link to an unknown site.

Comment: I guess you have some code creating the logo. The 500 Internal Server Error suggests that the code doesn't work.

Comment: ckeck the main.js   ` //jQuery(".menu-wraper img").width(jQuery('.header-logo img').width()).height(jQuery('.header-logo img').height());`

Comment: Can I ask why are you loading all these JS image plugins?

Comment: @ptts - the plugins are part of the original template

Comment: @Gildas.Tambo - There are no indicators in those parenthesis. I don't see how they are affecting the img.

Answer (score 0):

You image is 85*150, Do you need to change the picture with 85 * 85.

Comment: Yes, the original photo is 85x150, but the website is rendering it as 2x that.